# Delay in processing with Kafka Streams

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have created a Kafka Stream topology and I am having 1 Source and 2 Sinks.

I am using Spring Boot(2.1.9) with Kafka Streams and Not using Spring Cloud. Kafka Version 2.3.0

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
public class StreamStart {

    @Bean
    public KStream<String, String> process(StreamsBuilder builder) {
        KStream<String, String> inputStream = builder.stream("streamIn", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        KStream<String, String> upperCaseStream = inputStream.mapValues(value -> value.toUpperCase());

        upperCaseStream.to("outTopic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = upperCaseStream
            .flatMapValues(v -> Arrays.asList(v.split(" ")))
            .selectKey((k, v) -> v)
            .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
            .count(Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> as("counts-store"));

        wordCounts.toStream().to("wordCountTopic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));

        return upperCaseStream;
    }
}
```

The data flows in **outTopic** instantaneously whereas data getting displayed in **wordCountTopic** takes 20-25 seconds for each record.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Could you please write what Kafka stream setting u used

Comment: Left it default, any particular setting you are looking for?? I think most of the time is going in serializing it..

Comment: Try to disable caching via `Materialized.as(...).withCachingDisabled()`. For more details consult the docs about caching.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax you are correct and to the point. I will read about caching but just disabled it and results are instantaneous. But what is happening under the hood is I need to know. Is there any book which I can read about Kafka Streams and why nobody mentioned in the demo -Confluent, Spring Developer Conferences!!!

Comment: "Kafka Streams in Action" might be a good start